# Bounded of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C\left( {{\mathbb{R}^n}} \right)$. We define
$$\Phi \left( r \right) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in B\left[ {0,r} \right] = \left\{ {x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}:\left\| x \right\| \leqslant r} \right\}} \left| {f\left( x \right)} \right|,r > 0, \hfill \\
  \left| {f\left( 0 \right)} \right|,r = 0. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
Prove that $\Phi  \in C\left( \left[0 , \infty  \right) \right)$, nondecreasing and 
$$\left| {f\left( x \right)} \right| \leqslant \Phi \left( {\left\| x \right\|} \right),\forall x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $r<r', B(0,r)\subset B(0,r')$ implies that $\Phi(r)<B(r')$,

$x\in B(0,\|x\|)$ implies that $|f(x)|\leq \Phi(\|x\|)$.

To show that $\Phi$ is continuous, let $r>0$, $f$ is continuous implies that it is uniformly continous on $B(0,2r)$ implies that for every $c>0$, there exists $e>0$ such that $\|x-x'\|<e$ implies that $\|f(x)-f(x')\|<c$ for every $x,x'\in B(0,2r)$.

Take $e'=min(e,r/2)$, $|r-r'|<e'$ implies that $B(0,r')\subset B(0,2r)$. For every $x'\in B(0,r')$, ther exists $x\in B(0,r)$ such that $\|x-x'\|<e'$, we deduce that $|\|f(x)\|-\|f(x')\||\leq \|f(x)-f(x')\|<c$. This implies that $|\Phi(r)-\Phi(r')|<c$ and $\Phi$ is continuous.

Comment: The main problem is how to prove $\Phi$ is continuous. I can prove $\Phi$ is nondecreasing last inequality.